# Hibernate or sql auto roll back after commit

Tags: sql, hibernate

I am encountering some scenario's while updating and inserting data on to two tables

Table A  structure
A_ID, name ,status_code

Table B structure
B_ID, A_ID, previous_code, Curr_code

we are using hibernate.
first we are updating table A with new status code

```
  ex: if Initially status code is XYZ. we are changing it to MNO.
```

then we are inserting a record on to table B for tracking purpose.

Table A is parent table and Table B is child table.

the problem we are facing currently is , post successful updation of status in table A and insertion in table B, table A status is moving back to old state. Tom cat log does not show any exception . need help in figuring out how the status in Table A moved back to original state. Where as table B has new record inserted and available.

Comment: Show your code, can't know what you are doing wrong if you don't show it.

Comment: Probably a flush will solve things, but at least post your entities and your hibernate configuration/mapping.